# How to idiomatically format .apply{} in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, idioms

This might seem a little trivial, but since we read more code than we write, I want to know which of these versions looks nicer and more readable for you

```
private val VALUES by lazy {
    mutableListOf<Value>().apply {
        add(VALUE_1)
        add(VALUE_2)
        add(VALUE_3)
    }
}
```

OR

```
private val VALUES by lazy {
    mutableListOf<Value>()
        .apply {
            add(VALUE_1)
            add(VALUE_2)
            add(VALUE_3)
        }
}
```

In other words, should we care that the method (.apply) be on the same line as the caller, or the ending curly bracket to be aligned with the (.apply) method?

Comment: First if I would only use apply, second if I would be chaining more calls after apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html

**Chained call wrapping**

When wrapping chained calls, put the `.` character or the `?.` operator on the next line, with a single indent:

```
val anchor = owner
    ?.firstChild!!
    .siblings(forward = true)
    .dropWhile { it is PsiComment || it is PsiWhiteSpace }
```

The first call in the chain usually should have a line break before it, **but it's OK to omit it if the code makes more sense that way.**

So it's up to you :)